# Retrieving 2nd XML value

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2016, xml-namespaces

Code will run but it is not returning all the values I need from the below XML fragment. How do I make this iterative if and where > 1 current or former status exist, how do I adjust to return CurrentStatus_1 = 1 vs CurrentStatus_1 =31

```
  <account_status_counters>
    <account type="current" description="Pays Account as Agreed" status="1">31</account>
    <account type="current" description="Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due" status="3">1</account>
    <account type="current" description="Bad Debt" status="9">2</account>
    <account type="former" description="Pays/Paid 30-60 Days or Max 2 Payments Past Due" status="2">3</account>
    <account type="former" description="Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due" status="3">1</account>
    <account type="former" description="Bad Debt" status="9">6</account>
  </account_status_counters>


;with XMLNAMESPACES ('http://cp.com/rules/client' as ns1) 
select 
id,
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:admin/ns1:product_reference)[1]', 'varchar(15)') as Ref_Number, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status ="1"]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as CurrentDescription_1, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status ="1"])[1]', 'int') as CurrentStatus_1, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as CurrentDescription_2, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "])[1]', 'int') as CurrentStatus_2, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as CurrentDescription_3, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="current" and @status =" "])[1]', 'int') as CurrentStatus_3, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status ="1"]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as FormerDescription_1, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status ="1"])[1]', 'int') as FormerStatus_1, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status =" "]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as FormerDescription_2, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status =" "])[1]', 'int') as FormerStatus_2, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status =" "]/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as FormerDescription_3, 
cast(CS.CreditScoreXML as xml).value('(ns1:ncf_report/ns1:report/ns1:summary/ns1:account_status_counters/ns1:account[@type="former" and @status =" "])[1]', 'int') as FormerStatus_3 
from Database.dbo.CreditData CS
```

Expected Output with abbreviated descriptions
[image]

Current Outcome with abbreviated descriptions
[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a wild guess as the DDL and sample data population were not provided.

I was not sure regarding the Status(1-3) columns what is their source...It seems that the desired output screen shot has some discrepancies.

Check it out a solution below. It is significantly less verbose.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CreditScoreXML NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (CreditScoreXML) VALUES
(N'<ncf_report xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <admin>
        <product_reference>1234567890</product_reference>
    </admin>
    <account_status_counters>
        <account type="current" description="Pays Account as Agreed" status="1">31</account>
        <account type="current"
                 description="Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due"
                 status="3">1</account>
        <account type="current" description="Bad Debt" status="9">2</account>
        <account type="former"
                 description="Pays/Paid 30-60 Days or Max 2 Payments Past Due"
                 status="2">3</account>
        <account type="former"
                 description="Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due"
                 status="3">1</account>
        <account type="former" description="Bad Debt" status="9">6</account>
    </account_status_counters>
</ncf_report>')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://cp.com/rules/client') ,rs AS
(
    SELECT id, TRY_CAST(CreditScoreXML AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , rs.xmldata.value('(/ncf_report/admin/product_reference/text())[1]','VARCHAR(15)') AS Ref_Number
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="1"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS CDescription_1
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="1"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS CStatus_1
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="3"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS CDescription_2
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="3"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS CStatus_2
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="9"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS CDescription_3
    , c.value('(account[@type="current" and @status ="9"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS CStatus_3
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="2"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS FDescription_1
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="2"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS FStatus_1
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="3"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS FDescription_2
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="3"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS FStatus_2
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="9"]/@description)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS FDescription_3
    , c.value('(account[@type="former" and @status ="9"]/@status)[1]','INT') AS FStatus_3
FROM rs CROSS APPLY rs.xmldata.nodes('/ncf_report/account_status_counters') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----+------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | Ref_Number |     CDescription_1     | CStatus_1 |                 CDescription_2                  | CStatus_2 | CDescription_3 | CStatus_3 |                 FDescription_1                  | FStatus_1 |                 FDescription_2                  | FStatus_2 | FDescription_3 | FStatus_3 |
+----+------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|  1 | 1234567890 | Pays Account as Agreed |         1 | Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due |         3 | Bad Debt       |         9 | Pays/Paid 30-60 Days or Max 2 Payments Past Due |         2 | Pays/Paid 60-90 Days or Max 3 Payments Past Due |         3 | Bad Debt       |         9 |
+----+------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Great Solution Yitzhak!

Comment: @Ricky, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you.Please connect with me on LinkedIn.